# Handling a Cherimoya Tree

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, fruits, soft-fruit, fruit-drop

Does anyone have any experience with Cherimoya Trees???

We have one in our backyard.  Last year, it produced some decent size fruit.  This year, it seems like there are more fruits sprouting, and the tree is bending over almost to the ground.

Do I need to tie it to itself to keep it more upright?  Stake it?  Accept that it and its branches with fruit will need to be pruned short?

Also, I am not familiar at all with its watering needs, and if anyone has any recommendations.

[image]

Comment: Trying to post more photos...keyword trying...crappy Stack app

Comment: Can we get a picture of the whole tree or at least an estimate on size. The funny thing about that tree is that it can get extremely large. If your's is somewhere from 12-14 feet then that would suggest its been managed and probobly comes from a graft. If it is 20 ft tall then that is a different story and requires different management techniques.